# Dragablz - restore closed tab

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using dragablz + MahApps in C# WPF project and does anybody know how to restore closed tab in dragablz?

Any suggestions how to do that?

I know that there is property to "ConsolidateOrphanedItems" but I would like to know how to restore tab, if it was closed, e. g. user will click button and it will restore all tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out on my own...

dragablz:TabablzControl has "SourceCollection" and to restore tab, You just have to simple add it once again to SourceCollection as during close it is deleted from source collection.

Comment: Any tips about how to add it back to SourceCollection?

Comment: It depends how You want to achive it, but simplest way (no MVVM) is to name the tab that will be removed and added again by using x:Name property in XAML.
Then from code You can just do sth like that: DragablzName.AddToSource(NameOfTabThatYouWantToAdd);